# 日時を含むカラムに対してORDER BY ･･･　DESCを使用したのですが、データの並びが降順通りではありません

Tags: sql, vba

どうすれば狙った並びで抽出できるようになるかご教授頂きたいです。

使用したSQL

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM [sample.csv] WHERE type = '001' ORDER BY dt DESC"
```

csvファイルの中身

| name | type | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 001 | 2021/10/25 9:03:35 |
| bbb | 001 | 2021/10/25 9:04:19 |
| ccc | 002 | 2021/10/25 17:33:50 |
| ddd | 001 | 2021/10/25 17:37:40 |
| eee | 001 | 2021/10/25 10:24:18 |
| fff | 002 | 2021/10/25 9:40:31 |
| ggg | 002 | 2021/10/21 10:43:02 |

抽出結果

| name | type | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bbb | 001 | 2021/10/25 9:04:19 |
| aaa | 001 | 2021/10/25 9:03:35 |
| ddd | 001 | 2021/10/25 17:37:40 |
| eee | 001 | 2021/10/25 10:24:18 |
| ggg | 002 | 2021/10/21 10:43:02 |

この並びで抽出したい

| name | type | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ddd | 001 | 2021/10/25 17:37:40 |
| eee | 001 | 2021/10/25 10:24:18 |
| bbb | 001 | 2021/10/25 9:04:19 |
| aaa | 001 | 2021/10/25 9:03:35 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text Driver ですか？
schema.ini を定義して、dt を日付時刻型にするか、SQL中で日付時刻型にして ORDER BY すればよいかと。

「Schema.ini ファイル (テキスト ファイル ドライバー)」
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

「CSV取込からデータベース登録時の型変換について」
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/ja-JP/577381d0-4fa6-4c28-a84d-aba4b7667620/csv214623679612363124251248712540124791250512540124733033137682?forum=csharpgeneralja

Answer (score 1):

「CSV取込からデータベース登録時の型変換について」をヒントに解決しました。
実行環境がVBAでしたのでORDER BYで指定したカラム名に対してCDate関数を使うことで目的を達成することが出来ました。

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM [sample.csv] WHERE type = '001' ORDER BY CDate(dt) DESC"
```

「Schema.ini ファイル (テキスト ファイル ドライバー)」は設定の仕方に問題があったのか、これだけでは問題の解決には至りませんでしたがSchema.iniというモノを知りませんでしたので大変勉強になりました。